# LT spice showing a linear graph for common emitter amplifier

Tags: circuit-analysis, bjt, ltspice

I have created the following circuit for a common emitter amplifier (Voltage follower).

[image: Circuit]

According to my understanding, in VTC of CE amplifier, the graph should saturate after the output reaches +VDD. But in my case, it isn't. What am I missing? It will be of great help if you could help me improve my understanding.

[image: Graph]

Comment: In CE amplifier the output is at the collector not at the emitter.

Comment: Where did you get the model for this transistor?  Also, please add a checkmark to the answer that is most acceptable to you. We work hard for our check-marks! :-)

Comment: It was given as a part of our assignment. Is anything wrong with it? And, sure i will

Comment: @Helixxxx I have rolled back your question to a point where it doesn't contradict the answers given. I asked that if you make any amendments that you do so carefully and not disrespect the answers already given. This includes the title. Apart from anything else, the question (rolled-back to the earlier revision) is answered. You asked what are you missing and the answer provide that information i.e. no need to change the question i.e. live with the mistake in your question or, be very careful how you amend it indeed.

Comment: Also, in trying to re-describe your circuit as a common collector type, because there is a 7 kohm collector resistor, it doesn't fit that description either @Helixxxx - if I were you I'd choose an answer and formally select it and move on to a new question if there is something you still don't understand here. And, it goes without saying that you should not necessarily choose my answer.

Answer (score 9):

The graph response you are seeing is expected because when the input exceeds VDD current from the input flows directly through the base-emitter junction to the output. It is not acting as an amplifier anymore.

Also, a voltage follower is a common-collector amplifier not common-emitter. The terminology is used because the collector is common to both the input and output signals. It is also referred to as an emitter-follower.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the mistake! But why doesn't this happen when we use it in common emitter configuration? or taking output from the collector? there we get a saturation

Comment: Because in the common-emitter configuration the input voltage cannot flow directly to the output - there is not path to do so. If the common-emitter amplifier has an emitter resistor and the input is driven hard enough then the emitter will follow the input until eventually the base-collector junction is forward biased. Then the output will follow the input.

Answer (score 6):

> *According to my understanding, in VTC of CE amplifier, the graph
> should saturate after the output reaches +VDD. But in my case, it
> isn't. What am I missing?*

Because you've taken the output voltage from the emitter, the emitter is always around 0.7 volts below the base voltage i.e. it is acting as an emitter follower: -

[image]

The characteristic of the base-emitter junction is a forward biased diode in this configuration (a simple unity gain class A amplifier) except, when the base voltage is below around 0.7 volts (as you can see): -

[image]

And, due to the placement of a collector resistor of 7 kΩ, the base can freely rise above the supply rail even when base-collector becomes forward biased. This means you can raise the base as high as you want (within breakdown voltage limits) and the emitter will follow the base less 0.7 volts.

Because you have a 7 kΩ collector resistor and you are taking the output from the emitter, you can't re-describe your circuit as a common-collector type either.

Comment: How to find operating point for this kind of amplifier if let's say, the value of R2 is not given? My approach was to select the midpoint of vtc as operating point but how to find midpoint if there is no saturation?

Comment: @Helixxxx you have to decide what type of amplifier you want. At the moment your question says common-emitter but you are taking the output from the emitter (as per a common-collector or emitter-follower circuit). So, what is it that you want?

Comment: Common collector, I apologise for saying it wrong and creating confusions.

Comment: @Helixxxx, you can and should edit your question (even the title) to make it more clear.

Comment: @Helixxxx if you make any edits (to correct your mistakes), make sure you apply them at the end of your question. This is respectful to those who have left answers already. Make sure that the new edited section is clearly recognizable as such. If you edit the title make sure you do so in a way that doesn't cause current answers to be contradicted.